# How to interact with the running process in python?

Tags: python

For example, I opened power-shell manually in windows.Now I know process id of it. So I want to run commands on the process using python.

**Open power-shell manually.
Find its process id.
Execute commands using its process id.**

Please mention code to do it **

Comment: He should use subprocess library because that's why subprocess library was made. Dont suggest him using os because it can be problematic without for example the timeout option which subprocess library provides

Comment: @lapinkoira The subprocess module is of no use here. Justin Engel already said why.

Comment: @BlackJack repeating yourself wont make you right. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/ This PEP describes a new module for starting and COMMUNICATING with processes. subprocess is a module intented to replace os.system and can do the same being more flexible.

Comment: @lapinkoira Re repeating: Right back at you. ;-) I know that module and have used it extensively, I still don't see how to use it to communicate with a process that wasn't created by it. The point here is how do I attach to an _existing_ process‽ Why don't you simply tell? Edit: _os.system()_ can't do that either so I wonder why you mention it specifically‽

Comment: Whatever OP means with "run commands" on the process can be done with subprocess and shouldnt be done with os.system. And what do you mean with communicate? read the output? kill it? where is your code trying to do that? Why I should show you how to do it? you are not even trying.

Comment: @lapinkoira You are dead certain it can be done with the _subprocess_ module but admittedly don't even comprehend the question. You should show me to prove that it is possible because I claim it can't be done. Which I can't show obviously. I just can say there is nothing in the _subprocess_ module to attach to an existing process like the OP asks how to do. You say there is, so tell us what.  Unless you put some evidence on the table I'm out of this…

Answer (score -1):

You can do all that with the subprocess python standard library https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: He already said he knows the process id, he can do that with the subprocess library, how? stackoverflow is not a code writing tool tutorial. Do it yourself and then ask the right questions.

Comment: SO is for answering questions. If you don't feel like answering then simply refrain from it. The point is that the _subprocess_ module is no solution to the problem, not even part of it. If you think otherwise please care to explain why and _how_.

Comment: I have done exactly what he is asking  "Open power-shell manually. Find its process id. Execute commands using its process id." with the subprocess library, how? I am not going to copy paste my code here, just spend five minutes reading the subprocess library and, I repeat, do it yourself and then ask questions.

Comment: Show code or it did not happen.  Seriously I have no idea how to do that and I still claim there is no way to do it.  At least no obvious way that doesn't need some Windows system programming knowledge that isn't in the Python documentation for the _subprocess_ module.  I can't do it myself so that advise isn't helpful and I ask(ed) _how_‽

Comment: I don't know how to send a command to an *existing* powershell instance that is run in a *different* console window knowing only its pid. Most probably OP shouldn't do it i.e., OP should just run a command directly (perhaps using a new powershell process). If your answer meant to say it then at least you should show how to run a powershell-specific command via `subprocess`.